# How can I determine the correct positioning for rotated image with a rotated div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="img"/>
   <div class="underlay"></div>
</div>
```

The image is a picture of some text that is rotated by 10 degrees, however, the actual image is a regular rectangle. Here is the image:
[image]

Here is the css:

```css
.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.img {
   height: 20vh;
   width: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 5vh;
   left: 5vh;
}

.underlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Here is what it looks like with that:

[image]

My issue is, how do I position the underlay to perfectly match up underneath the image? I'm sure there is some trigonometry that can solve this but I just don't know where to start. I can manually update the underlay to match at some widths, but increasing the viewport width causes it to move out of sync which doesn't make sense as it's all defined by `vh`. I think this might have something to do with the left positioning but I'm not sure.

Comment: use `::before` for `background` or wrap it in a div and apply rotation to the div instead of text!!

Comment: @KunalTanwar `::before` on the image? The Defeat text is not text, it's an image that is already rotated in the image.

Comment: that use the second option of wrapping the image inside div and then rotating the `div`. **i.e.** instead of `.underlay` apply `background-color` on `.container`

Comment: @KunalTanwar But I don't want to rotate the image, it's already rotated to what I need.

Comment: can you post the `src` of `img` ??

Comment: @KunalTanwar I've provided the image in the question. The red Defeat text is an image. Its not a hosted image, its a file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's looking for something similar, I just had to add `transform-origin: top left;` to the underlay.